# Wordpress get_post_meta linking to diffrient post type

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to use post meta as link to different post types. 
I wrote something like this:

```
<li class="middle">
    Glass type: <span><a href="http://www.domain/diffrient-posttype/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'glass', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'glass', true); ?></a></span>
</li>
```

Its working fine, but i have problem with two words phrase. On the link im getting space.

Can you help me change space for a dash?
Do you have any better idea to solve this?

Comment: try esc_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'glass', true));
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url

Comment: esc is giving wrong adress. I must set straight link to other category which i cant get dynamic. 

That post is simillary but i dont know how to set it to code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
str_replace(' ', '-', $url);
```

or

```
preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '-', $url);
```

It will replace all white-space to - dash.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a [sanitize_title function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) that converts strings into the URL-friendly version.

```
$urlBase  = 'http://www.domain/different-post-type/';
$type     = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'glass', true);
$typeSlug = sanitize_title( $type );
$url      = $urlBase . $typeSlug;
?>
Glass type: <span><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $type; ?></a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out.. Final code looks like this:

```
<li class="middle">
Glass type: <span><a href="http://www.domain/diffrient-posttype/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'szklo', true)); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'glass', true); ?></a></span>
</li>
```